# How to add sender name another language in php mail

Tags: php, email

I tried to set sender name for my email sending system with Tamil language but server get it as SPAM email. When I use English sender name or without sender name, email sending system is working good. How to put another language for it.

Codes:

Without sender name:

```
$from = "aa@bb.com";
```

With English language sender name:

```
$from = "SenderName <aa@bb.com>";
```

With anther language sender name: (Example Tamil)

```
$from = "அனுப்புனர் பெயர் <aa@bb.com>";
```

When I tied anther language for sender name, sever send me that is SPAM email. How to solve this problem.

headers:

```
$headers = "From: $from" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Return-Path: aa@bb.com" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: What does `sever send me that is SPAM email` mean, exactly?  What is generating the message (sendmail? SpamAssassin?), and what is the exact message?

Answer (score 0):

Add Header to Your Mail

```
$header  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$header .= 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

// example
mail($to, $subject, $message, $header . $more_headers);
```

Comment: I already added headers but not working. please look at above code

Comment: I am facing the Same problem so I use PHPMailer https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer